# Assign full file path of FileUpload in textbox control back to FileUpload on postback

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have a FileUpload control in an UpdatePanel and when user select a file, the full file path will will be stored in a hiddenfield, and during postback, i would like to assign the full file path in the hiddenfield back to the FileUpload control textbox, possible to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible because you cannot assign a file path to the FileUpload control. Browsers don't allow that because it would be a security risk.

Comment: Ok so what would be an alternate to update an existing file. Can you please put it in the simplest possible words for me since I am a beginner.