# How to refer to a fileupload control opened in a new window through code

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have taken RowEditing feature to a new window in my program. Please have a look at my code first:

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
 lblSet.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[2].Text;
 MultiView1.SetActiveView(vRecord);

 btnSave.Visible = false;
 btnBacktoHome.Visible = true;
 //this.lblMedium.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[1].Text;


 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MEHDI-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PIMS;Integrated Security=True"))
 {
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
     {
         String sql = "select [DocumentID],[Ref],[Subject],[Src],[Dst],[Medium],[Date_Printed],[Date_Received],[Document_Type],[Action_Required],[Due_Date],[Actual_Date],[Content],[Tag],[Issue_No],[Attachment],[Notes],[Assigned_To],[Reply_Ref],[Priority],[Status],[Response],[Physical_File_No],[Physical_Rack_Location] from dbo.Documents1 where [DocumentId]=N'" + GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[2].Text + "'";
         cmd.Connection = con;
         cmd.CommandText = sql;
         con.Open();

         //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql,con);
         //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
         using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
         {
             adp.Fill(ds);
         }


         this.txtRef.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
         this.txtSubject.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString();
         this.ddlSource.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString();
         this.ddlDestination.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString();
         this.ddlMedium.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][5].ToString();
         this.txtDatePrinted.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][6].ToString();
         this.txtDateReceived.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][7].ToString();
         this.ddlDocumentType.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][8].ToString();
         this.cbxAction.Checked = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][9].Equals(cbxAction.Checked);
         this.txtDueDate.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][10].ToString();
         this.txtActualDate.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][11].ToString();
         this.txtContent.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][12].ToString();
         this.txtTag.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][13].ToString();
         this.txtIssue.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][14].ToString();

         //this.fileupload1 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][15] ;

         this.txtNotes.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][16].ToString();
         this.ddlAssignedTo.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][17].ToString();
         this.txtReplyRef.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][18].ToString();
         this.ddlPriority.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][19].ToString();
         this.ddlStatus.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][20].ToString();
         this.ddlResponse.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][21].ToString();
         this.txtPhysicalFileNo.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][22].ToString();
         this.txtPhysicalRackLocation.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][23].ToString();

         if (con != null)
         {
             con.Close();
         }
         btnUpdate.Visible = true;
         btnSearch.Visible = false;
         BindGrid();
     }
 }
```

}

When the RowEditing event fires, a new page is opened in my program in which all the fields of the record are rendered. Users edit any field they want, and when they press update button given at the bottom of this page, Rowupdating event fires.

Now as the code shows, I am referring to a textbox like :

```
this.txtRef.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
```

I am actually stuck with fileupload control. I am not sure how to refer to it on my new window. That is,

```
//this.fileupload1 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][15] ;
```

I have commented out this line of code for the other code to run smoothly. I have read online how to work with fileupload in a gridview but all the information I came across was about RowEditing design that is implemented within the GridView, not in a new window. Any help will be much appreciated. Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign file like that.
A better option is , in the edit view, show the file name in a label .
And then give a file upload control below that to upload a file, on uploading it replace the old file and update the label name.

Comment: all a file upload control does is "provide the 'path' to the file". Now firstly, why why cant a fileupload control be referenced through code .. when a textbox can be referenced (i.e., `this.txtRef.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();`) 
Secondly if all a fileupload does is pass the 'path' of the file, then why cant it do in RowEditing mode. I am sure it is possible but only for those who know how to do it.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929808/assign-full-file-path-of-fileupload-in-textbox-control-back-to-fileupload-on-pos

Comment: Ok fair enough. I get that now. I changed the design, added a template field and an item field (LABEL) and in that Item field's editItem mode , I added a "FileUpload" .. and tried to access fileupload that way .. all the code compiles alright but doesn't produce the output. Should I paste code to you if you have time and knowledge? Thanks

Comment: @RehanMehdi : ok do it.  will try

Comment: should I give you the link to my project?